# Get image src while using the .find() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I need to get the image src into a variable however i am using .find() to reference the current selected class image. my code is as such.

```
    var imagesrc = $(this).find(".shape img").attr("src");
    alert(imagesrc);
```

it is returning an undefined. where am i going wrong?

Comment: We need to see more... What's `$(this)` in this case? Show more code and setup a http://jsfiddle.net/ if possible.

Comment: Add the markup as well.

Comment: Arrow plz. Show us some more code

Comment: Try this `$(this).closest("img").attr("src");`

Comment: Replace `attr` with `prop`

Answer (score 1):

as the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/find/) says "will return a jQuery collection"

you should try changing your code in:

```
var imagesrc = $(this).find(".shape img").first().attr("src");
alert(imagesrc);`
```

Comment: But OP says imagesrc  is returning an undefined.,if it is returning collection of object it should not be undefined

Comment: i think it's imagesrc undefined, because the list returning has no attribute src

Comment: `$(this).find(".shape img")[0]` will return a native DOM element, not the first element found. Therefore calling `attr` on that will result in an error.

Comment: Then how should it is work find(".shape img")[0]

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan is right: find(...)[0] will return a native DOM element so you shuld write it like this: `$(this).find(".shape img").first().attr("src");` this will return a dom element, then .first() create a jquery rappresentation of the first object so finally you can apply your jquery functions

Answer (score 1):

First of all, find out what is the scope of **this** variable. 
Then probably you should take a look at [**.find() jQuery API**](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

Note that **find()** returns an array of matched elements not an single result.

p.s. each type you search through DOM for single element via class attribute you could not guarantee it is single one. Use ID attribute for such purposes.

Answer (score 0):

```
var imageSRCS = (function()
{
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img'); //get all image elements in document
    var SRCS = Array(images.length); //create a temporary array for our sources
    for(var i = 0; i<images.length; i++)
        SRCS[i] = images[i].src; //loop through our images and store the source in the array
    return SRCS; //return the temporary array to the imageSRCS variable 
}());
```

This will output a plain array of strings, the strings being every image source on the page. Swap the third line with

```
var images = document.getElementsByClassName('shape')[0].getElementsByTagName('img');
```

To only get the images inside the first element with the shape class, which i believe is what you were trying to do originally.

Remember the output is an array so if your only expecting one src from this perhaps try.

```
var imageSRC = document.getElementsByClassName('shape')[0].getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src;
```

Which gets the source of the first image of the first element with the shape class